# Accessing attributes/nodes in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have some XML that I am trying to read then write specific information to the console, my XML file is located at https://aaronlilly.github.io/demo/demo.xml

or also listed here:

```
<DogCenter xmlns="http://schema.dogsite.com/xsi">
  <dogActiveState>Available</dogActiveState>
  <useDefaultGuardDog>false</useDefaultGuardDog>
  <enableGuardDog>true</enableGuardDog>
  <guardTimerSeconds>7</guardTimerSeconds>
  <useDogOther>true</useDogOther>
  <forceHumanToPlay>true</forceHumanToPlay>
  <forceDogInCrate>false</forceDogInCrate>
  <forceDogFoodLimit>true</forceDogFoodLimit>
  <numberConsecutiveBallsBounce>4</numberConsecutiveBallsBounce>
  <makeBarkingNoiseIfMailMan>true</makeBarkingNoiseIfMailMan>
  <outgoingDogCenter>
    <TrainerId>Alpha</TrainerId>
    <name>Argoni</name>
  </outgoingDogCenter>
  <dogCenterList>
    <centerDetails>
      <TrainerId>Bingo</TrainerId>
      <available>true</available>
      <tagNumber>80</tagNumber>
      <extension>8</extension>
      <isLogOffAllowed>false</isLogOffAllowed>
      <dogLevel>12</dogLevel>
    </centerDetails>
    <centerDetails>
      <TrainerId>Case</TrainerId>
      <available>true</available>
      <tagNumber>93</tagNumber>
      <extension>1</extension>
      <isLogOffAllowed>false</isLogOffAllowed>
      <dogLevel>12</dogLevel>
    </centerDetails>
    <centerDetails>
      <TrainerId>Buddy</TrainerId>
      <available>false</available>
      <tagNumber>60</tagNumber>
      <extension>82</extension>
      <isLogOffAllowed>false</isLogOffAllowed>
      <dogLevel>12</dogLevel>
    </centerDetails>
    <callCenterDetails>
      <TrainerId>Apex</TrainerId>
      <available>true</available>
      <extension>83</extension>
      <isLogOffAllowed>false</isLogOffAllowed>
      <dogLevel>3</dogLevel>
    </centerDetails>
    <centerDetails>
      <TrainerId>Marle</TrainerId>
      <available>false</available>
      <tagNumber>37</tagNumber>
      <extension>5</extension>
      <isLogOffAllowed>false</isLogOffAllowed>
      <dogLevel>3</dogLevel>
    </centerDetails>
    <cnterDetails>
      <TrainerId>Arrow</TrainerId>
      <available>true</available>
      <extension>84</extension>
      <isLogOffAllowed>false</isLogOffAllowed>
      <dogLevel>5</dogLevel>
    </centerDetails>
    <centerDetails>
      <TrainerId>Aaron</TrainerId>
      <available>true</available>
      <extension>64</extension>
      <isLogOffAllowed>false</isLogOffAllowed>
    </centerDetails>
    <centerDetails>
      <TrainerId>AlphaAlternate</TrainerId>
      <available>true</available>
      <extension>65</extension>
      <isLogOffAllowed>false</isLogOffAllowed>
    </centerDetails>
    <centerDetails>
      <TrainerId>Monkey</TrainerId>
      <available>false</available>
      <tagNumber>64</tagNumber>
      <extension>14</extension>
      <isLogOffAllowed>false</isLogOffAllowed>
      <dogLevel>3</dogLevel>
    </centerDetails>
    <centerDetails>
      <TrainerId>Mona</TrainerId>
      <available>true</available>
      <tagNumber>05</tagNumber>
      <extension>85</extension>
      <isLogOffAllowed>false</isLogOffAllowed>
      <dogLevel>12</dogLevel>
    </centerDetails>
  </dogCenterList>
</DogCenter>
```

What I'd like to do is write in example,

```
TrainerID = Bingo , Available = True, dogLevel = 12;
```

for each TrainerId (ie bingo, apex, mona)

so far, what I have got is this

```
XmlElement elem = (XmlElement)doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
Console.Write("{0} = {1}", elem.Name, elem.InnerText);
```

Which writes `dogActiveState = Available ;`

I have tried a for loop

```
for (int x = 0; x < elem.ChildNodes.Count; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}"",elem.Name, elem.InnerXml);
}
```

and

```
for (int x = 0; x < elem.ChildNodes.Count; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{x}={x+1}",elem.Name, elem.InnerXml);
}
```

but I haven't quite mastered the syntax here.

Comment: this will get me the names of the elements, ie TrainerID, available. 

  XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xml));
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine(rdr.LocalName,
                            Console.WriteLine(rdr.Name);
                        }
                    }

Comment: You may want to consider using [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) if your documents are not too large, and you have any experience with LINQ. It makes for a nice easy to read syntax for getting information out of XML documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [XmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementsbytagname) to get the `callCenterDetails` elements, and access their child elements using the [XmlNode indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.item#System_Xml_XmlNode_Item_System_String_).
Here is an example:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("demo.xml");
var callCenterDetails = doc.GetElementsByTagName("callCenterDetails");
for (var i = 0; i < callCenterDetails.Count; i++)
{
    var trainerId = callCenterDetails[i]["TrainerId"].InnerText;
    // ...
}
```